# using flash application locally

Tags: flash

I am trying to use a flash player locally. I downloaded this player:

https://github.com/mstandio/SaladoPlayer

when I am trying to open the player in my browser, I am getting this error:

```
>SaladoPlayer 1.3
>Could not access local files, error: #2148
>Add directory of unzipped files to Global Security Settings panel if you want to use player on local mashine
```

Clicking on the page redirect to a macromedia site where you can set the Global security. I add my directory to the list of directory that should be trusted, but I am still getting the same error.

What else should I do to do this?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html go to this site and add to the list directory where your files are located. You can just add entire drive partition and never be bothered about this again

You can also set up local http server and access your files through it.